# How to check if there are results with Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

In the past I would do something like so:

```
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_email="' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customer_email']) . '" ';
  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  // if there are no hits...
  if(mysql_num_rows($res) == FALSE) {
```

Today I am doing the same thing however with prepared statements:

```
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers where customer_email = ? LIMIT 1");
  if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['customer_email']))) {
```

The 2nd line of my prepared statement if($stmt... is that "if this query gets a result" or is it "if this query is executed regardless of results or not ie if it executes without error".

What I'm trying to work out is with prepared statements how do you do the equivalent of mysql_num_rows() == FALSE?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `rowCount()` method of `PDOStatement` to get the number of rows returned:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers where customer_email = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['customer_email']));
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
   //fetch stuff...
}
```

Or, if `rowCount()` proves to be unreliable, you can do this:

```
$all = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(count($all)) {
   //loop through the set...
}
```

Comment: `rowCount()` is a method, and officially it is only supported for affected rows in manipulations, but yeah, for MySQL this works as the number of rows in a resultset.

Comment: +1 But note that `rowCount()` only works if you use buffered queries.  No interface to MySQL can tell you how many rows are in the result set before it has fetched them.

Comment: On a slightly different note, how do you see what the final query looked like? ie I would go "echo $sql" if I want to see what I'm performing to check if the variables are coming through right - whats the PDO way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement and not the number of rows returned by select query,
for select query I use :
`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`
And
`echo count($lignes);`

```
<?php
$PARAM_hote='localhost'; 
$PARAM_port='3306';
$PARAM_db='test'; 
$PARAM_user='root'; 
$PARAM_pwd=''; 
try
{
$connexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$PARAM_hote.';dbname='.$PARAM_db, $PARAM_user,$PARAM_pwd);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();
}
$requete_prepare_1=$connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM `test_mysql`"); 
$requete_prepare_1->execute();
$lignes=$requete_prepare_1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo count($lignes); 
?>
```